# JavaScript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I am a beginner and I am currently working on a memory card game. Help me, please.

Here is my code to which the error message applies:

HTML

```
<div id="game-board" class="board clearfix"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var createBoard = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        var cardElement = document.createElement('img');
        cardElement.setAttribute('src', "images/back.png");
        cardElement.setAttribute('data-id', i);
        document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].addEventListener('click', flipCard);
        document.querySelector('game-board').appendChild(cardElement);
    }
}


createBoard();
```

Comment: paste your html

Comment: I think issue in querySelector.If class based selection use document.querySelector(".game-board"); or Id based use document.querySelector("#game-board");

Answer (score 1):

You can't access elements without attaching them to DOM.. as your code you are creating img tag and trying to access them before appending them.
Here is the modified code

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].addEventListener('click', flipCard);
document.querySelector('game-board').appendChild(cardElement);
```

```js
var createBoard = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var cardElement = document.createElement('img');
        cardElement.setAttribute('src', "images/back.png");
        cardElement.setAttribute('data-id', i);
        
        document.querySelector('.game-board').appendChild(cardElement);
        document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].addEventListener('click', cardElement);
    }
}


createBoard();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='game-board' class='game-board'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. That makes sense; however, when I appended the element prior to adding the event listener, I still received the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

The error "cannot read property 'appendChild' of null" means that your line with appendChild evaluates to

```
null.appendChild(cardElement);
```

In other words, `document.querySelector('game-board')` must be evaluating to null and null doesn't have an `appendChild` method.

Solution: Probably the selector inside `querySelector` is wrong; check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

If game-board is a class it should be

```
document.querySelector('.game-board')
```

If game-board is an id it should be

```
document.querySelector('#game-board')
```

Comment: This is very insightful and helped me to understand the error message much better; however, after adding the correct syntax for an id, the error message is still occuring.

Comment: Have you tried @sheplu's of moving the code towards the end of the file? If your code is before the definition of the `<div id="game-board" ...`, then the `document.querySelector` function can't find it because the `div` hasn't loaded yet.